# Is it worth parting out a set to sell without the minifigs?

Tags: shopping

I wanted to sell my Lego in a bulk, but then decided I don't have a reason not to sort it out.

I do believe I have the Ninjago Earth Dragon (2509), but before I find the pieces, I know a few things about it's condition immediately.

The bricks are good. I've never had problem with the treatment therefore no scratches or broken stuff.

There are NO minifigures or accessories (I sold all my figs in bulk for 20 dollars a while ago, I know I am an idiot)

There is no box or instructions... Just the bricks. Is it still worth the effort?

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE!

Answer (score 3):

Not having the minifigs certainly hurts the value of a set, but it may still be worth parting out the set depending on how valuable your time is to you.

If you haven't already done so, you can use the Price Guide feature on Bricklink to get a rough idea of what [your set](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=2509-1#T=P) can sell for.

You can also browse the current listings for the set to get an idea of how much missing minifigs hurt the price. For [that set](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=2509-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D), it looks like not having minifigs knocks off about 40% of the value of the set ($24 USD vs $42 USD).

Comment: I saw this particular set in a "new condition" go for more than two hundred bucks. Is that because of the box and blurb, or is it the value of the Lego itself?

Comment: Bricklink says that this set has been sold 5 times in the last 6 months for 67-120 Euros (new and complete). Sometimes you see overpriced offers or (mock?) sales. But these cannot be used as reference. I don't really understand why someone would offer this set for 200 if there are already 5 offers for 100 Euros.

Comment: Some Bricklink sellers are quite unpleasant people who just want to showcase their collection. They have no intention of selling, they just want to rub it in your face that they have something that you can't have...

Answer (score 2):

If it is complete (except for the minifigs), I would sell it separately because it is a relatively small set (low weight) with some interesting parts. You might get 10 Euro/Dollars which is still much more than the 10-15 Euros/kg in a bulk sale.

If you have several Ninjago sets, it might be a good idea to sell all of them in one single Ebay auction. Make sure to include all set numbers in the description. When the rare parts (dragon heads etc.) are in very good condition, you could mention this explicitly.

In the past, I bought several sets without minifigs. I looked for offers including the word "without" in the search. So, it might be advantegous to include "without minifigs" in the title.

I know, there are a lot of "could" and might" in the answer, but from my buyer's perspective you might :) consider these things.